# create javascript class with classname including dot (my.class.name)?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to create a class in javascript where the classname can have dots.

```
var my.class.name = function(){
  /*........*/
}
```

Well, i know this can be achieved by initializing **my={}** & **my.class = {}** . But Is there a way to avoid doing this manually ?

Comment: First you ask whether identifiers can contain periods, and then go on to say it can be done by initializing objects first? In `my={}; my.class = {}`, the periods are not part of the identifier.

Comment: No, classnames cannot contain dots. You can put your class in a nested ("namespace") object, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [ECMA Script 5.1 Specification for *Identifier Names and Identifiers*](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6), only `$` and `_` are allowed apart from the valid Unicode characters. Quoting from the specifications,

> The Unicode identifier grammar is based on both normative and informative character categories specified by the Unicode Standard.

So, you cannot declare a variable or a function with a dot in it.

But, it will not stop you from defining that function as part of an object, like this

```
var functions = {};
functions["my.class.name"] = function() {...};
functions["my.class.name"](...);              // Call it with arguments
```

Comment: how do you call this function ?
functions.my.class.name !!
It did not work

Comment: @Dante You cannot call it like that, you have to call it like `functions["my.class.name"](....your arguments go here ....);`

Answer (score -1):

I looked at this and found an answer

```
my.function = () => {}
```

or

```
my.function = function() {}
```

Comment: Actually, this does not create a class with a dot in the name - Instead, it creates a property named "function" on the object named "my", and assigns an anonymous function to that property. The closest you can come to OP's desired functionality is given in @thefourtheye's answer above.